# Copy multiple files with same naming format from different directories using Batch file

Tags: batch-file, copy

I'm trying to copy a specific file name that ends with _current in many different directories. Each directory has the same folder structure. I need to be able to copy all files that end in _current from each of the sub-folders in each directory. I've tried the code below as a test, not using my real directory names rather using test directories.

```
for /R "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testfolder\*\ABCD" %%f in (*_current) do copy %%f C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\abcd
```

Comment: You can't use a wildcard in the path option. Why do you need to specify a wildcard and then hard code another directory after that?

Comment: You cannot use a wildcard as a 'mid' directory. Without specifically showing us your directory structure, which would be a simple case of using the `tree` command, and pasting the results into your question, we'd have to guess what you're trying to do. This is one such guess: `@For /D %%G In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\testfolder\*") Do @For %%H In ("%%G\ABCD\*_current") Do @Copy /Y "%%H" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\abcd" 1>NUL`. An example `tree` command would be `%SystemRoot%\System32\tree.com "%UserProfile%\Desktop\testfolder" /F /A`.

Comment: My directory structure looks like this C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\CompanyA\subfolder1\file_current and each "Company directory has 4 subfolders but I only want to get a file out of a specific subfolder, I've got around 600 company folder directories that it needs to parse